# Find the most import features for a SVM classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, svm

I'm training a *binary classifier* using `python` and the popular `scikit-learn` module's `SVM` class. After training I use the `predict` method to make a classification as laid out in [sci-kit's SVC documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#classification).

I would like to know more about the significance of my sample features to the resulting classification made by the trained `decision_function` (support vectors). Any strategies for evaluating feature significance when making predictions with such a model are welcome.

Thanks!
Andre

Answer (score 1):

So, how do we interpret feature significance for a given sample's classification?

I think using a linear kernel is the most straightforward way to first approach this because of the significance/relative simplicity of the `svc.coef_` attribute of a trained model. [check out Bitwise's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/39311).

Below I will train a linear kernel SVM using `scikit` training data. Then we will look at the `coef_` attribute. I will include a simple plot showing how the dot product of the classifier's coefficients and training feature data divide the resulting classes.

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = data.data                # training features
y = data.target              # training labels
lin_clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
lin_clf.fit(X,y)

scores = np.dot(X, lin_clf.coef_.T)

b0 = y==0 # boolean or "mask" index arrays
b1 = y==1
malignant_scores = scores[b1]
benign_scores = scores[b1]

fig  = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("score breakdown by classification", fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
score_box_plt = ply.boxplot(
    [malignant_scores, benign_scores],
    notch=True,
    labels=list(data.target_names),
    vert=False
)
plt.show(score_box_plt)
```

[image: score_box_plt]

As you can see we do seem to have accessed the appropriate intercept and coefficient values. There is obvious separation of class scores with our decision boundary hovering around 0.

Now that we have a scoring system based on our linear coefficients we can easily investigate how each feature contributed to final classification. Here we display each features effect on the final score of that sample.

```
## sample we're using X[2] --> classified benign, lin_clf score~(-20)
lin_clf.predict(X[2].reshape(1,30))

contributions = np.multiply(X[2], lin_clf.coef_.reshape((30,)))
feature_number = np.arange(len(contributions)) +1

plt.bar(feature_number, contributions, align='center')
plt.xlabel('feature index')
plt.ylabel('score contribution')
plt.title('contribution to classification outcome by feature index')
plt.show(feature_contrib_bar)
```

[image: contribution to classification outcome by feature index]

We can also simply sort this same data to get a contribution-ranked list of features for a given classification to see which feature contributed the most to the `score` we are assessing the composition of.

```
abs_contributions = np.flip(np.sort(np.absolute(contributions)), axis=0)
feat_and_contrib = []
for contrib in abs_contributions:
   if contrib not in contributions:
       contrib = -contrib
       feat = np.where(contributions == contrib)
       feat_and_contrib.append((feat[0][0], contrib))
   else:
       feat = np.where(contributions == contrib)
       feat_and_contrib.append((feat[0][0], contrib))

# sorted by max abs value. each row a tuple:;(feature index, contrib)
feat_and_contrib
```

[image: contribution-ranked list including feature index]

From that ranked list we can see that the top five feature indices that contributed to the final score (of around -20 along with a classification 'benign') were `[0, 22, 13, 2, 21]` which correspond to the feature names in our data set; `['mean radius', 'worst perimeter', 'area error', 'mean perimeter', 'worst texture']`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have Bag of word Featurization and you want to know which words are important
for classification then use this code for linear svm

```
weights = np.abs(lr_svm.coef_[0])
sorted_index = np.argsort(wt)[::-1]
top_10 = sorted_index[:10]
terms = text_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for ind in top_10:
    print(terms[ind])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SelectFromModel in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#feature-selection-using-selectfrommodel) to get the names of the most relevant features of your model. [Here is an example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_select_from_model_boston.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-select-from-model-boston-py) of extracting the features for LassoCV.

You can also check out [this example](https://medium.com/@aneesha/visualising-top-features-in-linear-svm-with-scikit-learn-and-matplotlib-3454ab18a14d) which makes use of `coef_` attribute in SVM to visualize the top most features.